# Azure core tools - how to specify a different key name when fetching connection string

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cli

Is there a way to tell the tool what field name in my local.settings.json file I want to update when fetching a connection string?  so specifically, when I run this command:

```
func azure storage fetch-connection-string $STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME
```

by default, it grabs the name of my storage account (mystorage123) and appends "_STORAGE" to it.  So you end up with something like this:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "mystorage123_STORAGE": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=mystorage123;AccountKey=<key>"
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {}
}
```

I would like it just to create a json field / key that just matches the actual account name - in this case "mystorage123".
Is there a way to do this?
I know I can write powershell code to update my json file manually.  But it'd be better if I can just tell the command what to call the field.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like it just to create a json field / key that just matches
> the actual account name - in this case "mystorage123". Is there a way
> to do this? I know I can write powershell code to update my json file
> manually. But it'd be better if I can just tell the command what to
> call the field.

I don’t think there is such a way. This connection string is originally been spliced.